# Возможно ли заполнять окно новыми элементами при runtime?

Tags: wpf, разработка-игр, runtime

Шалом знатоки, я только учусь программировать, решил попробовать сделать крестики нолики с целью ознакомления с алгоритмами, ну и выбор пал на WPF т.к. технология относительно новая, а я любопытный.
Сразу же столкнулся с проблемой, я хочу сделать три варианта игры, 3 в ряд(3х3), 5 в ряд (10х10) и 7 в ряд (15х15). Для этого я сделал стандартное винформ меню и там 3 элемента. Я пытаюсь сделать так что при нажатии на соответствующий элемент меню окно перерисовывалось и наполнялось необходимым количеством кнопок-ячеек игровой доски с генерируемыми идентификаторами. Возможно ли это? Или нужно в конструкторе делать 3 отдельных окна для каждого типа игры? Возможно я вообще не правильно все это себе представляю ввиду нехватки опыта и это можно сделать проще? Заранее признателен.

Comment: Таки шалом. Конечно, можно, проблем никаких нет. Самый простой вариант — вы можете добавлять элементы в `Children`. Но лучше освоить MVVM и делать всё по науке.

Comment: А ещё у нас есть прекрасный [список литературы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/10105), там и про WPF есть.